# Replicating RegisterGradient and gradient_override_map in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Following is the code for registering a gradient and overriding an operation's gradient in tensorflow.

```
# Registering a gradient
some_multiplier = 0.5 

@tf.RegisterGradient("AdaGrad")
def _ada_grad(op, grad):
    return grad * some_multiplier 

# Overriding 
g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({"Ada": "AdaGrad"}):
    model.loss = tf.identity(model.loss, name="Ada")
```

I want to replicate the same thing in keras. I couldn't find any way to do it after searching a lot of things.

I tried the following code but it didn't work. 
The gradient is not being modified. I got the same result with and without gradient override. I checked it with setting `some_multiplier` to zero.

```
model = Model(...) # Keras model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adadelta, metrics=['accuracy']) # Compiling Keras Model

@tf.RegisterGradient("AdaGrad")
def _ada_grad(op, grad):
    return grad * some_multiplier 

g = tf.get_default_graph()
with g.gradient_override_map({"Ada": "AdaGrad"}):
    model.total_loss = tf.identity(model.total_loss, name="Ada")
```

Comment: Welcome to S.O.  The phrase "didn't work" is ambiguous.  To help others provide an answer to your question, best to also include a brief description of the "actual" results (error, wrong result, etc...), and what you "expected" to happen instead.

Answer (score 0):

The same approach should work, but you need to make sure to use the graph of the Keras model. How you retrieve the graph changes a bit if you are using [`keras.model.Model`](https://keras.io/models/model/) or [`tf.keras.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model):

```
model = Model(...) # Keras model
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=adadelta, metrics=['accuracy']) # Compiling Keras Model

@tf.RegisterGradient("AdaGrad")
def _ada_grad(op, grad):
    return grad * some_multiplier 

# with keras.model.Model
from keras import backend as K
g = K.get_session().graph
# with tf.keras.Model
g = model.graph

with g.gradient_override_map({"Ada": "AdaGrad"}):
    model.total_loss = tf.identity(model.total_loss, name="Ada")
```

Comment: model.graph is not working. It is giving an attribute error: 'Model' object has no attribute 'graph'. Is there any other way to get keras graph?

Comment: @Sahitya Oh wait, are you using [`tf.keras.Model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model) or [`keras.model.Model`](https://keras.io/models/model/). If it is the second one, you can access the graph through the [backend](https://keras.io/backend/) like `K.get_session().graph` (see [issue #3223](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3223)).

Answer (score 0):

`gradient_override_map` of TensorFlow doesn't work with most Keras operations.
The simplest way that I found is to replace the operation in Keras with TensorFlow implementation of it.

for example, suppose that relu activation is considered, then it will be simply:

```
tf.keras.activations.relu = tf.nn.relu
# <function tensorflow.python.keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0)>
# <function tensorflow.python.ops.gen_nn_ops.relu(features, name=None)>
```

Works with most networks, as usually only first parameter is used for ReLU in Keras models.
In case of other operations which do not match you can create a wrapper function around tf analog in order to match parameters with Keras.

**ReLU example with VGG16 network.**

Register gradient.

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("GuidedRelu")
def _GuidedReluGrad(op, grad):
    return tf.where(0. < grad, gen_nn_ops.relu_grad(grad, op.outputs[0]), 
tf.zeros_like(grad))
```

Initialize the network with custom gradient.

```
sess = tf.Session()
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
tf.keras.backend.set_session(sess)
with graph.gradient_override_map({'Relu': 'GuidedRelu'}):
    model = tf.keras.applications.VGG16()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. In my case, I was using "gradient_override_map" trying to implement "guided backprop".

```
@tf.RegisterGradient("GuidedRelu")
def GuidedReluGrad(op, grad):
    grad_filter = tf.cast(grad > 0, "float32")
    output_filter = tf.cast(op.outputs[0] > 0, "float32")
    return output_filter * grad_filter * grad
```

I was using VGG16 as a predicting model.

```
model = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
predicted = np.argmax(model.predict(np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)))
```

I had tried the below code but in vain.

```
with K.get_session().graph.gradient_override_map({'Relu': 'GuidedRelu'}):
    # here is implementation to get gradients
    # but "GuidedRelu" is not used
```

So, I had created a new Graph and Session before calling "gradient_override_map" and succeeded to change gradient function from "Relu" to "GuidedRelu".

```
new_graph = tf.Graph()
with new_graph.as_default():
    new_sess = tf.Session(graph = new_graph)
    with new_sess.as_default():
        with new_graph.gradient_override_map({'Relu': 'GuidedRelu'}):
            new_model = VGG16(include_top=True, weights='imagenet')
            # here is implementation to get gradients with new graph/session
            # "GuidedRelu" is used
```

I don't know why the former doesn't work. but I hope this can help.